# Declaring variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-directive

Is there any way can I declare `url` variable with different way?
Because it is not working for my code.
I found this code from here. But it is working fine for this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/aSjwk/1/

```
 app.directive('backImg',  function(){
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        // name: '',
        // priority: 1,
        // terminal: true,
        // scope: {}, // {} = isolate, true = child, false/undefined = no change
        // controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {},
        // require: 'ngModel', // Array = multiple requires, ? = optional, ^ = check parent elements
        // restrict: 'A', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
        // template: '',
        // templateUrl: '',
        // replace: true,
        // transclude: true,
        // compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, function transclude(function(scope, cloneLinkingFn){ return function linking(scope, elm, attrs){}})),
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var url = attrs.backImg;
            element.css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
                'background-size' : 'cover'
            });
            console.log(url)
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div  back-img='{{el.images}}.png'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a CSS property to a URL value, you have to wrap the URL in quotation marks.

Try this instead.

```
element.css({
         'background-image': 'url("' + url +'")',
         'background-size' : 'cover'
});
```

Comment: It worked. I have been struggling for 2 hours to find answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `url` should be `surl` since you're putting the backImg value into `surl`.

Try changing that.

```
var turl = element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + surl +')',
            'background-size' : 'cover'
        });
```

Comment: I'm unsure if I helped you spot the invalid variable name or if your initial code release was typed out wrong. Regardless, I'm glad you got it working.